# How to detect water level in a transparent container?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

[image: Original image]

I am using opencv-python library to do the liquid level detection. So far I was able to convert the image to gray scale and applying canny edge detection the container has been identified.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cv2 import threshold, drawContours


img1 = cv2.imread('botone.jpg')
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
#convert the image to grayscale
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(imgray,120,230)
```

[image: I applied different threshold effect to see which edge detection is better. Apparently, the final edge detection was chosen for directly on gray-scale image.]

I need to know how to find water level from this stage.
Should I try machine learning, or is there any other option or algorithm available?

I took an approach of finding out the horizontal line in the edge detected image. If the horizontal line crosses certain threshold I can consider it as level.But the result is not consistent.

I want to know if there are any other approaches i can go with or white papers for reference?

Comment: How about showing us a couple of sample images? And your current code.

Comment: I am not clear what you want to measure. I am not a chemist, but I can see an inverted, pear-shaped glass thing on the left of the picture that appears to have 2 water levels in it, and a tall narrow, straight-sided, presumably glass thing on the right that also appears to have two water levels in it... which of those 4 things do you want?

Comment: Oh sorry, i should have kept only cropped image. Well i just want to find out the liquid level in the inverted, pear-shaped glass. As you can see 2 water levels in it, the upper one is the actual water level. This is the complexity of a problem with naked eye itself it is difficult to figure out which one is the water level. This is just the sample image i have taken,  I would want my algorithm to identify liquid level in any transparent object given dark, constant background.

Comment: Can you control the lighting? It may help to light from a different direction, or with a different colour light, or to put a diffuser (piece of baking paper maybe) over the light source...

Comment: Also, do you have just the original image (without your grayscale and edges etc.) as well please, at a decent resolution rather than me cropping a tiny image out of a large one?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you would do that with `numpy` and `opencv`, because I use ImageMagick (which is installed on most Linux distros and is avilable for OSX and Windows), but the concept should be applicable.

First, I would probably go for a Sobel filter that is rotated to find horizontal edges - i.e. a directional filter.

```
convert chemistry.jpg -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 sobel.jpg
```

[image]

Then I would probably look at adding in a Hough Transform to find the lines within the horizontal edge-detected image. So, my one-liner looks like this in the Terminal/shell:

```
convert chemistry.jpg -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 -hough-lines 5x5+30 level.jpg
```

[image]

If I add in some debug, you can see the coefficients of the Sobel filter:

```
convert chemistry.jpg -define showkernel=1 -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 -hough-lines 5x5+30 sobel.jpg
Kernel "Sobel@90" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from -2 to 2
Forming a output range from -4 to 4 (Zero-Summing)
 0:         1         2         1
 1:         0         0         0
 2:        -1        -2        -1
```

If I add in some more debug, you can see the coordinates of the lines detected:

```
convert chemistry.jpg -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 -hough-lines 5x5+30 -write lines.mvg level.jpg
```

**lines.mvg**

```
# Hough line transform: 5x5+30
viewbox 0 0 86 196
line 0,1.52265 86,18.2394  # 30      <-- this is the topmost, somewhat diagonal line
line 0,84.2484 86,82.7472  # 40      <-- this is your actual level
line 0,84.5 86,84.5  # 40            <-- this is also your actual level
line 0,94.5 86,94.5  # 30            <-- this is the line just below the surface
line 0,93.7489 86,95.25  # 30        <-- so is this
line 0,132.379 86,124.854  # 32      <-- this is the red&white valve(?)
line 0,131.021 86,128.018  # 34
line 0,130.255 86,128.754  # 34
line 0,130.5 86,130.5  # 34
line 0,129.754 86,131.256  # 34
line 0,192.265 86,190.764  # 86
line 0,191.5 86,191.5  # 86
line 0,190.764 86,192.265  # 86
line 0,192.5 86,192.5  # 86
```

As I said in my comments, please also think about maybe lighting your experiment better - either with different coloured lights, more diffuse lights, different direction lights. Also, if your experiment happens over time, you could consider looking at differences between images to see which line is moving...

Here are the lines on top of your original image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mark.Let me try the same steps in opencv. I guess this should work. Apparently I started with Sobel filter today only.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple filters using CV, and as @Mark Setchell answered in the previous answer, Sobel filter for detecting Horizontal line is one of the methods and if it doesn't work properly consider using "cv2.filter2D" with a Sobel Y(Detects Horizontal lines) kernel.

The proper Kernel to be used in your case is as follows:

```
Kernel= np.array
([
[-1,-2,-1],
[ 0, 0, 0],
[ 1, 2, 1]
]) 
Image_Sobel_Y = cv2.filter2D(Image,-1,Kernel) 
# -1 means that the output will use the same depth(data type, how many bits)
```

north neighbouring pixels are negative and south are positive(Dark in the top, lighter in the bottom). You can reverse the polarities and see which one suits you.