# How to detect water level in dirty transparent tank with computer vision?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, imagemagick

I've just started my first computer vision project where I need to measure the level of rain water in an outside tank. The tank is white but not opaque so that the water can be seen (it is grayer). There is also an armature around the tank which adds vertical and horizontal lines.

[image]

I read and try this similar question [How to detect water level in a transparent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238267/how-to-detect-water-level-in-a-transparent-container), but I got a "hairy" result (too many lines in all angles). I used ImageMagick 6.9.7.

[image]

The best results I could get so far was to convert the RGB color space into HSV with Gimp. I say best results because the unfilled volume appears more clearly.

[image]

If I then apply `convert  input.jpg  -colorspace gray -colors 2  -normalize threshold.png` I get this image on which I could count the white pixels and compare their number to the gray one count (although there are some black ones too in the white area).

[image]

But I am unsure it will work since the picture lightning conditions will change throughout the measures (all year round, 3 times a day), and the picture may be noisy because eventually it will be taken from a low end webcam ( 360 x 288 ). The picture showed here was taken from a decent smartphone.

So I feel there should be a better and more reliable way to achieve my goal (measure the water level with computer vision). Could somebody advise me on what to do (eg which filters / transform to apply) , and how I could reliably separate the tank column in 2 areas (filled / unfilled parts) ?

*Please note : I know I could invest in a water level detector (reportedly they are not expensive), or do it with a wire, or with a floating part linked to a string, or with ultrasound, ... but I want to do it with computer vision and the devices I already have ;-)*

Any help appreciated,

Edit: Finally ultrasound detector is so much easier
Unfortunately the image from the webcam, and the tank armature did not allow me to detect the water level reliably. 
 So I ended up pluging in an ultrasound detector since it is so much easier and quicker, for a cost of ~6€.

Comment: If this is a very low cost, *"belt and braces"* approach, you could maybe try floating something on top of the water to make it different above the level to how it is below - maybe a sheet of reflective white polystyrene that lightens the area above the water and stops light getting below the surface, assuming it is top-lit. Or a sheet of wood painted red on top to make the void above the water level more saturated in colour. Or maybe do the first polystyrene idea and turn on a light above the water before measuring. Just some random thoughts.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't get yourbidea clear. From where should the camera point to. Now it is from the side. Do you suggest to put the camera on top of the tank (in the big hole where the water pipe comes in) and to point it downwards to the polystyrene and measure its size in pixel ? The lower the water level the smaller the polystyrene will appear.

Comment: No I wasn’t suggesting moving the camera at all.

Comment: Also, the metal cage lines can interfere with an edge finding algorithm you use